# Datatype mismatch error in access using group by

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database with a table that looks something like this:

[ID], [Date Filed], [Open/Closed], [Investigator Name]

I want a query that gives me the number of open and closed cases for each of the investigators. I was trying to use this query:

SELECT [Investigator Name], Count(*) AS Total
FROM [main table]
WHERE [Date Filed] Between "start_date" And "end_date" and [Open/Closed]=-1
GROUP BY [Investigator Name];

But I am getting an error that says: "Datatype mismatch in criteria". I was thinking it was because of the null values in the column "Investigator Name", I tried using Nz, but then the query does not consider the column name to be in the group by expression. I've tried playing around here but nothing worked.

PS: I have only written the query for open values, if there is a way to get both open and closed values, that would be awesome.

Comment: Where will the `start_date` and `end_date` values be coming from? Right now they are just string literals (i.e., the actual strings `"start_date"` and `"end_date"`, not date values), which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Shouldn't it ask me to enter the values when I try to run my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be a Parameter Query (and be prompted for the `start_date` and `end_date` values) then the parameters need to be enclosed in square brackets as well. Here is the SQL code that the query builder in Access put together:

```
PARAMETERS start_date DateTime, end_date DateTime;
SELECT [main table].[Investigator Name], Count([main table].ID) AS Total
FROM [main table]
WHERE ((([main table].[Date Filed]) Between [start_date] And [end_date]) AND (([main table].[Open/Closed])=True))
GROUP BY [main table].[Investigator Name];
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be asked  [end_date] and [start_date] you shoud write

```
PARAMETERS [end_date] DateTime, [start_date] DateTime;
SELECT [Investigator Name], Count(*) AS Total
FROM [main table]
WHERE [Date Filed] Between [start_date] And [end_date] and [Open/Closed]=-1
GROUP BY [Investigator Name];
```